# Расположение изображений в один ряд и текст поверх них

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как расположить 3 изображения в один ряд и добавить текст поверх них так же, как показано на макете?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Krub', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-left: 37px;
}

header {
  background: url(./images/img1.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 1200px;
}

nav,
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu li {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 41px;
  margin-right: 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.titles-first {
  font-size: 90px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 220px;
}

.titles p {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2;
}

.button {
  background-color: #cd8586;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 17px 0;
  margin: 102px auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image .text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
}

.image .text .line-1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.image .text .line-2 {
  color: #aaa;
}

footer {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 325px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.settings li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2;
  font-style: italic;
}

.settings-2 li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2;
  font-style: italic;
}

.settings-3 li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2;
  font-style: italic;
}

.settings {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 198px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.settings-2 {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 198px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.settings-3 {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 198px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.black {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
  height: 97px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 42px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Страница для вёрстки</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Krub:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#links">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="titles">
        <div class="titles-first">
          Web Design
        </div>
        <p>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris <br> condimentum , ut fermentum massa justo sit amet <br> erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Really?</a>
  </header>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./images/img2.png">
      <div class="text">
        <div class="line-1">amet condimentum</div>
        <div class="line-2">dolor</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./images/img3.png">
      <div class="text">
        <div class="line-1">Lorem Cursus</div>
        <div class="line-2">Ligula</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./images/img4.png">
      <div class="text">
        <div class="line-1">Condimentum Ultricies</div>
        <div class="line-2">Consectetur</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="settings">
        <h2 id="links">Follow us</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pinterest</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-2">
      <div class="settings-2">
        <h2>Get to know us</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-3">
      <div class="settings-3">
        <h2>Locations</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Detroit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Florida</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Las-Vegas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">California</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <div class="black">
    Copyright © 2016 @samiralley
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Код покажите пожалуйста

Comment: @SeeSharp ага, а вдруг Вы украдёте его? )))

Comment: @UModeL если бы не увидел что вы не тот человек который задал вопрос, не сдержался бы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой вариант устроит?

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image .text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
}

.image .text .line-1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.image .text .line-2 {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/1_small.jpg">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="line-1">line 1</div>
      <div class="line-2">line 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/793021684064419840/RjEjM6z5.jpg">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="line-1">line 1</div>
      <div class="line-2">line 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dreem-pics.com/uploads/posts/2017-10/1508077709_0_small.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="line-1">line 1</div>
      <div class="line-2">line 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кек, обажаю когда минусят за правильный ответ..

Comment: Это я постарался.... Считаю, что не стоит отвечать на подобные вопросы... Ни примера верстки... Ни желания отвечать на комменты... Просто, оставил заказ, кто-нить да ответит...

Comment: Air, это мой ответ - моё желание ему помочь. Может - не может, его дело. Моё помочь. А по поводу оценок, давно заметил, многие пропускают этот момент.

Comment: Я добавил код. Прошу прощения, что сразу не добавил. Это моя первая практика, так что пока не совсем всё полностью понимаю в плане вёрстки.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 `display:block`... Че-т не хардкорно... В истинном CSS все должно быть криво. Даешь `display:flex`:)